# Make Emacs: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng15

Tags: emacs, build

When I am trying to build emacs, it stopped with:

```
./configure   #(no problem)
make

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng15
```

What is this -lpng15? Any lib missing in my system?

Comment: What is your OS? I estimate it to be Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm using Linux. `$ uname -a
Linux nick-ThinkPad-X200 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Actually, after trying several approach, (and switched to new window manager), Emacs successfully was successfully built. I don't why. BTW: May I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's possible to delete any question. It should be possible but, better to post the solution as an answer to help others having similar problems. Actually sometimes I did that answering my own question after finding the solution.

Back to your question: It was obviously about configure script's being unable to find the libpng files. Today I tried to install Emacs-24.4.1 from source into my Lion Mac mini and came across the same problem "cannot find -lpng15" Actually there were already libpng15.dylib files (.dylib is roughly equivalent of linux' .so files) under /usr/X11/lib, but configure script must have been somehow unable to find them. Then I downloaded & installed  `libpng-1.6.15` into /usr/local/lib and then Emacs installed successfully.

In your case, the installation of a new Window Manager must have put the libpng15.so files into a findable location so that the configure script has located the -lpng15

Comment: `the installation of a new Window Manager must have put the libpng15.so files into a findable location so that the configure script has located the -lpng15` I think you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this library is for supporting gif and png. In my case I didn't need that, so I run the following configuration

```
./configure --with-x-toolkit=no  --with-xpm=no --with-jpeg=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no --with-png=no
```

I know this question has already an answer, but maybe this is useful to future readers